# Run ionic app on device and connect with local server

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic app. It has a login feature. Now I am running the whole backend logic in my local computer. Is there a way to run my app on the device and connect that from the device to local server?

Answer (score 2):

> Connecting Ionic App to a Local Server

## 1. Setup a Local Server

Obtain the IP of your Computer (Local Server) which would probably be of the form, `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` or `172.x.x.x`

On **Windows**, the command is: `ipconfig`

On **macOS**, the command is: `ifconfig`

## 2. Connect you Device to the same Wifi Network

## 3. Code changes

In you code, make all network calls (HTTP requests) to the IP obtained by the previous two steps.

## 4. Run the App

Use, `ionic cordova run` to run the application on your Device.

#### 5. If you still have questions, come here and comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ya, It's Possible.

## Step 1

Run your backend with a port (your pc IP),

## step 2

Connect ur phone and pc with the same network

## Step 3

Connect ur phone to ur pc

## step 4

Check whether ur phone enabled `USB Debugging` mode. If not means please on it

## step 5

Then run in treminal `ionic cordova run android -c -l`

Comment: How can I run my backend with aport my pc IP? I am using nodejs expressjs.

Comment: Run your back-end code in your IP then connect the phone and your pc with the same network. you can run the app

Comment: Run your backend code in your IP? How can I use my ip in `app.listen(3000)`? It only accepts port as you can see.

Comment: you are using node js means it automatically get ur IP. And run its running also Ip with port

Comment: "And run its running also Ip with port" I am not sure what do you mean about that? I am simply using same `app.listen(3000)` and do not use any ip with it but when I send any request using such as `http://10.0.0.63:3000/` then I am not receiving any response on the server.